# The best way to save changes from DataGridView using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have `DataGridView` which is binded to `ObservableCollection` in my View Model.
Items in collection implements `INotifypropertyChanged`. Items load some fields from EF and some fields requesting from web.

User can edit some fields in `DataGridView`. How can I save changes of the items in database when user edit cell (without any "submit" button)?

I can subscribe to every item in list `PropertyChanged` event when fill the list. Is this a good way?

Something like this in event handler:

```
    private void Item_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (TradeItemViewModel) sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == "CountLimint" || e.PropertyName == "PriceLimit")
        {
            var repository = new ItemsRepository();
            var dto_item = repository.GetById(item.ClassId, item.IntanceId);
            dto_item.CountLimit = item.CountLimint;
            dto_item.PriceLimit = item.PriceLimit;
            repository.Update(dto_item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create ViewModel class for the item of your collection and update database in the setter.

```
public class TradeItemDatabaseViewModel
{
    private readonly TradeItem _Model;

    public int CountLimit
    {
        get { return _Model.CountLimit; }
        set(int value) 
        {
            if(Equals(_Model.CountLimit, value) == true) return;

            this.SaveCountLimit(value);
            _Model.CountLimit = value;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameOf(this.CountLimit));
        }           
    }

    private void SaveCountLimit(int value)
    {
        var repository = new ItemsRepository();
        var dto_item = repository.GetById(item.ClassId, item.IntanceId);
        dto_item.CountLimit = item.CountLimint;
        repository.Update(dto_item);
    }
}
```

Then bind `ObservableCollection<TradeItemdatabaseViewModel>` to `DataGridView.DataSource`

Above is raw example based on your question.